# ng-table doesn't load any data from $data

Tags: angularjs, html, ngtable

I'm trying to load data to an ng-table in the following way,

The HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ng-table.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycont as vm">

<div class="container">
    <table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}</td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ng-table.min.js"></script>

<script src="table.js"></script>
</body>
```

The Angular Script (in *table.js*)

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"])

.controller('mycont', ['ngTableParams', function(ngTableParams) {
    var self = this;

    var data = [
        {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
        {name: "Alan", age: 45},
        {name: "Tony", age: 36}
    ];

    self.tableParams = new ngTableParams({}, { dataset: data});
}])
```

but I get a table, even with the filters, but without any data.

Please help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I copied your code to Plunker and it works fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/F1sA0QCbV15RCsW0tddt?p=preview), the only changes I made were the URLs to the JavaScript and CSS files for ngTable.

Double-check your JavaScript console and network log for errors.

Since I need to include code to include links to Plunker, these are the URLs I used:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get **404: Not Found** for these links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

You can't use $ in scope variable names on view, go through [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api%22Angular%22) docs carefully.

Change **$data** to **vm.tableParams.dataset**

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.tableParams.dataset">
            <td title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">
                {{user.name}}
            </td>
            <td title="'Age'" filter="{ age: 'number'}" sortable="'age'">
                {{user.age}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of the [intro code](http://ng-table.com/#/) I noticed that `NgTableParams` is with uppercase N.

Comment: any output on the js console?

Comment: try accessing $data through `vm.$data`